# TestStack.White "freezes" after launching another application

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, ui-automation, white-framework

I'm new in testing UI with **TestStack.White** library. And I stucked with the next problem.

1. Main and child applications with WPF controls
2. OPEN button in the main app calls the child app
3. After event `Button.Click()` on button OPEN child app appears, and nothing happens.
4. Any statement cannot be  performed until child app will be closed (it can be clearly seen during debugging).
5. I can neither get title of new window, nor get any control state, nor write something to trace.
6. Child application can be launched separately, and all controls are available

Who is faced with such problem?

Comment: Could you provide some more information on how you are launching the second application from the WPF application? Are they both WPF applications and are they in the same solution or are you launching a child process?

Comment: They are both WPF applications. There is no VisualStudio solution for these apps, I have only releases of compiled versions. 1st application has button in UI which opens 2nd application.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution/workaround for the same?

Comment: No, I haven't. Will be glad to get any proposals.